# Error while installing gatsby image plugin

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

Getting this error every time i try to install gatsby-image-plugin . Tried gatsby clean and running yarn as well. Tried different versions of gatsby but that didn't help either .

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details? Platform, versions, OS, etc

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem?